# Passing a fix id to all action in controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller **ScoreController** so all this actions in this controller needs an id called **ScheduleId** so i have to**viewbag** and again restore that .My question is how can i set this value as an fix value and all of my view (i.e **Edit**,**Delete**,**Create**,**list**) and actions use that without passing ?

My controller code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using EducationMVC.Models;
using EducationMVC.PresentationClass;
using EducationRepositor;
using DomainClasses;
namespace EducationMVC.Controllers
{
    public class ScoreController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Score/
        private readonly ScoreRepository obj = new ScoreRepository();
        PresentationClass.DateConverter objconverterDate=new DateConverter();
        public ActionResult Index(string scheduleId)
        {
            List<ScoreStudentPresentation> objlist=new List<ScoreStudentPresentation>();
            List<Score> model = obj.GetStudentlistOfSchedule(scheduleId);
            foreach (Score t in model)
            {
                ScoreStudentPresentation objpres=new ScoreStudentPresentation();
                objpres.ConfirmScore = objconverterDate.ConvertToPersianToShow(t.DateOfSubmit);
                objpres.Family = t.Student.LastName;
                objpres.Name = t.Student.Name;
                objpres.Score = t.Point;
                objpres.StudentNumber = t.Student.StudentId.ToString();
                objpres.id = t.Id.ToString();
                objlist.Add(objpres);

            }
            ViewBag.ScheduleId = scheduleId;
            return View(objlist);
        }
        public ActionResult Create(string ScheduleId)
        {

            return View("Create");

            // return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Score score)
        {
            obj.AddNewScore(score);
            obj.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Score");
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            return View(obj.FindScoreById(id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Score score)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.Update(score);
                obj.Save();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Score");
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see i passed the **ScheduleId** to Create and **Index** and i have to this for another actions because i need **scheduleId** .i want to avoid this.

Best regards.

Comment: http is stateless protocol, you need to store value in session or viewbag and use it to and fro on every request

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bad idea if you override *OnActionExecuting* method and add a ViewBag item, for instance, **ViewBag.ScheduleId** within that method, then, use a hiddenInput in a shared view such as _Layout (perhaps in some particular place such as View folder in **Score**).

Also, you can define an parameter named *scheduleId* in each action method, or use *Request["ScheduleId"]*

Comment: Thanks Mr Dehghan.So as you said i have to repeat the ScheduleId in each actions again!!am i right?

Comment: @EA, Not necessarily if you could utilize reflector functionalities :)

Comment: Ok .Thank you (mamnon aghaye dehghan)